# Changing subfig \subfref format

Tags: cross-referencing, formatting, subfloats

I'd like to know how to hack `subfig` in order to change the format of `\subref`. The current format, when `subfig` is initialized with `listofformat=parens` yields output like 4.5(b) . I'd like to add a space between the 4.5 and (b).

I know the documentation of `subfig` says that new formats can be defined with       `\DeclareSubrefFormat{hkeyword valuei}{hcodei}` but I haven't managed to actually get hat to work.

Does anyone have an example of how the format can be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option `listofformat` controls the way subfloat numbers are typeset in the List of Figures/Tables and the actual format of the string produced by the `\subref` command. To change this format, you have to declare a new format using `\DeclareCaptionListOfFormat` and then use this new format in `\captionsetup`. In the second argument of the `\DeclareCaptionListOfFormat` command, `#1` represents the float number and `#2` represents the subfloat number. So to obtain the space between the float number and the subfloat number in the the LoF/LoT and when using `\subref`, you'll have to do something like the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[lofdepth]{subfig}

\DeclareCaptionListOfFormat{myparens}{#1~(#2)}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{listofformat=myparens,listofnumwidth=4em}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}

\subref{fig:sub1}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[Text 1 In Toc][Text 1 in document\label{fig:sub1}]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{name1}}\qquad
  \subfloat[Text 2 In Toc][Text 2 in document\label{fig:sub2}]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{name2}}
  \caption{test}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Here's the List of Figures obtained:

[image]

and a fragment of the document, showing the output produce by `\subref`:

[image]

If you only want to change the way `\subref*` (note the star) typesets the string associated to a subfloat, without affecting the entries in the Lof/Lot, you have to declare a new format using `\DeclareSubrefFormat` and then use this format in `\captionsetup`. In the second argument of `\DeclareSubrefFormat` you can use `#1` (the string associated to the float), `#2` (the string associated to the subfloat), `#3` (the value of the float counter) y `#4` (the value of the counter associated to the subfloat). A little example producing a space between the float and subfloat numbers:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[lofdepth]{subfig}

\DeclareSubrefFormat{myparens}{#1~(#2)}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{subrefformat=myparens}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}

\subref*{fig:sub1}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[Text 1 In Toc][Text 1 in document\label{fig:sub1}]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{name1}}\qquad
  \subfloat[Text 2 In Toc][Text 2 in document\label{fig:sub2}]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{name2}}
  \caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Now the LoF looks like this:

[image]

and the fragment showing the output of `\subref*`:

[image]